# Running `mklink` in ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, process, symlink

I am working on a c# program that needs to be compatible with Windows and Linux (Mono).

I am trying to create a symbolic link in both platforms and I am using ProcessStartInfo in order for this to work. I haven't tried this on Linux yet but on Windows I am using the following code

```
ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo();

                    process.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    process.UseShellExecute = false;
                    process.FileName = "mklink";
                    process.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    process.Arguments = "/D " + webFolder + "MyFolder" + webFolder + "MyFolder_" + version;
                    Process.Start(process);
```

When I run the above code I get

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file
>   specified

If I run mklink in command prompt it works fine.

I've had a look on Google and it says about doing a [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] but this isn't going to work on Linux.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`mklink` is a command of the `cmd.exe` program, not a stand-alone program.

To run `mklink`, you have to actually invoke `cmd.exe` with an appropriate set of parameters, like this:

```
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c mklink " + argumentsForMklink);
```

Comment: Glad to help... Note that when you run this on Linux (assuming you're running C# there), you *probably* don't need to run mklink through a shell (not done much Mono so not 100% sure).

Comment: I don't think there is a mklink command so I need to run a separate command for linux which would be ``ln -fs source target``. I'm doing a check first to see which OS it is running on and performing the command accordingly.

Comment: @Boardy: Good point. `ln` is a stand-alone command (I believe) so would not require a shell processor under Linux.

Comment: I had problems running `mklink` on a remote machine by means of `PSEXEC \\someserver mklink ...`. Your answer gave me the crucial hint to use `PSEXEC \\someserver cmd /c mklink ...` instead, which worked well.